# Looping String in Dictionary

Tags: python, string, encryption

I'm trying to loop a string of keys into the dictionary so as to retrieve the values in the dictionary.

Could anyone help to see why is my code not returning the output expected?

```
def decipher_message(msg: str, guide:dict):
    message = []  
    for letter in msg:
        result = guide.get("letter")
        message.append(letter)
        
    return message
```

The rationale behind my code is that i'll first create an empty list of message and for each letter in the `msg` (string inputted by users), it returns the value of the dictionary. After which I'll append the value and store it in the list []. At the end of it, returning the list of values. Not exactly sure which step went wrong so would appreciate any experts to contribute and help a beginner out here.

I'm not supposed to be hard-coding both strings and dictionary into my function but for example purposes, the following is the string and dictionary that my function is trying to read:

```py
string: "esbtr dgh abzqg! vhe ghz yzqtcjxx qx qt btgesjz cbxepj!"

dictionary: {'a': 'm', 'b': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'd': 'y', 'e': 't', 'f': 'v', 'g': 'o', 'h': 'u', 'i': 'x', 'j': 'e', 'k': 'j', 'l': 'w', 'm': 'f', 'n': 'z', 'o': 'd', 'p': 'l', 'q': 'i', 'r': 'k', 's': 'h', 't': 'n', 'u': 'g', 'v': 'b', 'w': 'q', 'x': 's', 'y': 'p', 'z': 'r'})
```

The expected output should be: `thank you mario! but our princess is in another castle!`

Comment: I don't think you're appending values. `message.append(letter)` appends the string.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `message.append(result)` so that the message output is filled with the values from the dictionary rather than the input string?

Comment: I see two main issues in the code (copy paste issues?): `guide.get("letter")` should be `guide.get(letter)` and the result is never used (next line wrong). Read again what you just told us what the code is supposed to do and then review your code. It should help a lot.

Comment: hi both, thanks for the inputs! i've swapped out message.append to results instead of "letter" but my current output is returning a list of None values

Comment: @beginner_pythonuser Tobias has given you the solution for that part. Replace `"letter"` with `letter` in the get method. The answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors: one `guide.get("letter")` and one in `message.append(letter)`.

- For the former error, You are literally searching for the key "letter" in this case. Change it to `guide.get(letter)`. You could also change `guide.get(letter)` to `guide.get(letter, letter)`. The second argument is optional, and corresponds with the value that should be returned whenever the key is not found. This is  useful to extract the spaces and exclamation marks in your string.
- For the latter, you should append the letter that you extracted from the dictionary,and not the `letter` itself.  Change it to `message.append(result)` and you should be good to go!
- At this point, you will still have a list as return object. If you really want to have it as a string, you can join the elements of the list together to a string:

  ```py
  message_as_string = ''.join(message)
  ```

If you do not understand why this is the solution, leave a comment and I can elaborate a bit more!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: and yes, I would like to return the elements as strings instead of list! But I'm facing a TypeError issue since the list contains None and I'm unable to return the string value. Wondering if there's supposed to be additional steps to take to prevent this?

Comment: I think the suggestion in the first bullet point should work for you. The get method returns None if it didn't find the key (in your case, that would be spaces and exclamation marks since these are not in your guide dictionary). You can overrule this behavior by using an extra argument that says which character should be returned (in your case the letter i.e. the space/exclamation mark itself, so that's why there is 2 times letter in the get function). Does that make sense?

Comment: What you could also do is add the space and exclamation mark to your guide dictionary. In that case, you won't have any None in your message list

Comment: Hey @icdumort, yes that makes perfect sense! Truly appreciate your help on this and I love the super clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
string = "esbtr dgh abzqg! vhe ghz yzqtcjxx qx qt btgesjz cbxepj!"
dictionary = {'a': 'm', 'b': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'd': 'y', 'e': 't', 'f': 'v', 'g': 'o', 'h': 'u', 'i': 'x', 'j': 'e', 'k': 'j', 'l': 'w', 'm': 'f', 'n': 'z', 'o': 'd', 'p': 'l', 'q': 'i', 'r': 'k', 's': 'h', 't': 'n', 'u': 'g', 'v': 'b', 'w': 'q', 'x': 's', 'y': 'p', 'z': 'r'}

def decipher_message(msg: str, guide: dict) -> str:
    message = []
    for character in msg:
        message.append(guide.get(character, character))
    return ''.join(message)

print(decipher_message(string, dictionary))
```

Or, if you want it to be really concise then:

```
def decipher_message(msg: str, guide: dict) -> str:
    return ''.join(guide.get(c, c) for c in msg)
```

Comment: Hi Olvin, that's exactly what I'm trying to do! Could you please explain to me some of the steps that you've taken right there? 

I'm a little confused at the line "message.append(guide.get(character,character))

Comment: i'm also wondering why is it that my above code is returning me None values but it doesn't in yours? thank you!

Comment: @beginner_pythonuser I suggest you review the relevant documentation here:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: got it! appreciate it a lot :)